# Removing '#$A' from Delphi string

Tags: delphi, string, replace, escaping

I am modifying a delphi app.In it I'm getting a text from a combo box. The problem is that when I save the text in the table, it contains a carriage return. In debug mode it shows like this.

```
newStr := 'Projector Ex320u-st Short Throw '#$A'1024 X 768 2700lm'
```

Then I have put

```
newStr := StringReplace(newStr,'#$A','',[rfReplaceAll]);
```

to remove the '#$A' thing. But this doesn't remove it.

Is there any other way to do this..

Thanks

Comment: You might want to consider removing `#$D` too while you are at it.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Remove the quotes around the #$A:

```
newStr := StringReplace(newStr,#$A,'',[rfReplaceAll]);
```

The # tells delphi that you are specifying a character by its numerical code.
The $ says you are specifying in Hexadecimal.
The A is the value.

With the quotes you are searching for the presence of the #$A characters in the string, which aren't found, so nothing is replaced.

Comment: Thanks alot... I will mark this correct tomorrow.coz gotta leave now.

Comment: @Andreas, I totally agree that this is a very good answer absolutelly deserving to be accepted. But, in general it is a good idea and it is SO good practice, too, just wait some longer to see if a simpler, more complete, better explained answer is posted.

Comment: Yep.. I was in a rush to leave.Therefore didn't have 5 mins to mark this. So I have done today.. Thanks alot. @Andreas : I guess this answers your question. :)

Answer (score 6):

Adapted from http://www.delphipages.com/forum/showthread.php?t=195756

The '#' denotes an ASCII character followed by a byte value (0..255).

The `$A` is hexadecimal which equals `10` and `$D` is hexadecimal which equals `13`.

`#$A` and `#$D` (or `#10` and `#13`) are ASCII line feed and carriage return characters respectively.

Line feed = ASCII character `$A` (hex) or `10` (dec): `#$A` or `#10`

Carriage return = ASCII character `$D` (hex) or `13` (dec): `#$D` or `#13`

So if you wanted to add 'Ok' and another line:

```
Memo.Lines.Add('Ok' + #13#10)
```

or

```
Memo.Lines.Add('Ok' + #$D#$A)
```

To remove the control characters (and white spaces) from the beginning
and end of a string:

```
MyString := Trim(MyString)
```

Why doesn't Pos() find them?

That is how Delphi displays control characters
to you, if you were to do `Pos(#13, MyString)` or `Pos(#10, MyString)` then it
would return the position.